# Why does my output for triple quotes have two newlines?

Tags: python

I was trying to print sans undertale with a glowing eye (which meant I had to use a seperate print line for the variable instead of the triple quotes), but the output has two empty lines, above and below the part that has color (line with XD), I'd like to remove. I assume its a problem with triple quotes print functions meeting one-line (as in not triple quote) print functions Here is the code:

```
from termcolor import colored, cprint
text = colored('8XD8', 'cyan')

print ('''

                888888888888888888
            8888                  8888
          88                          88
          88                          88
        88                              88
        88                    888888    88
''')
print ("\t\t88                    ", text,"    88")
print ('''
        88    888888    88    888888    88
          88          888888          88
        8888  88                  88  8888
        88    8888888888888888888888    88
        88      88  88  88  88  88      88
          8888    88888888888888    8888
         88888888888             8888888888
       88  888888888888888888888888888888  88
    8888  88    88      88      88    88  8888
    88      88    888888  888888    88      88
  88    8888  888888    88    888888  8888    88
  88        88    88          88    88        88
  88          88  88          88  88          88
    88      88    8888      8888    88      88
      8888  88    88          88    88  8888
        888888    88888888888888    888888
          8888    88888888888888    8888
        8888888888888888888888888888888888
        8888888888888888  8888888888888888
          888888888888      88888888888
      888888        88      88        888888
      88          8888      8888          88
        8888888888              8888888888
''')
```

The output looks like this:

```
                888888888888888888
            8888                  8888
          88                          88
          88                          88
        88                              88
        88                    888888    88

        88                     8XD8     88

        88    888888    88    888888    88
          88          888888          88
        8888  88                  88  8888
        88    8888888888888888888888    88
        88      88  88  88  88  88      88
          8888    88888888888888    8888
         88888888888             8888888888
       88  888888888888888888888888888888  88
    8888  88    88      88      88    88  8888
    88      88    888888  888888    88      88
  88    8888  888888    88    888888  8888    88
  88        88    88          88    88        88
  88          88  88          88  88          88
    88      88    8888      8888    88      88
      8888  88    88          88    88  8888
        888888    88888888888888    888888
          8888    88888888888888    8888
        8888888888888888888888888888888888
        8888888888888888  8888888888888888
          888888888888      88888888888
      888888        88      88        888888
      88          8888      8888          88
        8888888888              8888888888
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Okay, cool. So what's wrong with it? Please read [ask].

Comment: Every print add a newline to the end by default.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python3 print can be given an end parameter, by default print will end in a newline so you need to overwrite it with something else such as the following

print ('''

```
                888888888888888888
            8888                  8888
          88                          88
          88                          88
        88                              88
        88                    888888    88
''', end = "")
print ("\t\t88                    ", "text","    88", end = "")
print ('''
        88    888888    88    888888    88
          88          888888          88
        8888  88                  88  8888
        88    8888888888888888888888    88
        88      88  88  88  88  88      88
          8888    88888888888888    8888
         88888888888             8888888888
       88  888888888888888888888888888888  88
    8888  88    88      88      88    88  8888
    88      88    888888  888888    88      88
  88    8888  888888    88    888888  8888    88
  88        88    88          88    88        88
  88          88  88          88  88          88
    88      88    8888      8888    88      88
      8888  88    88          88    88  8888
        888888    88888888888888    888888
          8888    88888888888888    8888
        8888888888888888888888888888888888
        8888888888888888  8888888888888888
          888888888888      88888888888
      888888        88      88        888888
      88          8888      8888          88
    8888888888              8888888888
''')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
print ('''

                888888888888888888
            8888                  8888
          88                          88
          88                          88
        88                              88
        88                    888888    88''')
print ("        88                    ", text,"    88")
print ('''        88    888888    88    888888    88
          88          888888          88
        8888  88                  88  8888
        88    8888888888888888888888    88
        88      88  88  88  88  88      88
          8888    88888888888888    8888
         88888888888             8888888888
       88  888888888888888888888888888888  88
    8888  88    88      88      88    88  8888
    88      88    888888  888888    88      88
  88    8888  888888    88    888888  8888    88
  88        88    88          88    88        88
  88          88  88          88  88          88
    88      88    8888      8888    88      88
      8888  88    88          88    88  8888
        888888    88888888888888    888888
          8888    88888888888888    8888
        8888888888888888888888888888888888
        8888888888888888  8888888888888888
          888888888888      88888888888
      888888        88      88        888888
      88          8888      8888          88
        8888888888              8888888888
''')
```

On my computer I got:

```
                888888888888888888
            8888                  8888
          88                          88
          88                          88
        88                              88
        88                    888888    88
        88                     8XD8     88
        88    888888    88    888888    88
          88          888888          88
        8888  88                  88  8888
        88    8888888888888888888888    88
        88      88  88  88  88  88      88
          8888    88888888888888    8888
         88888888888             8888888888
       88  888888888888888888888888888888  88
    8888  88    88      88      88    88  8888
    88      88    888888  888888    88      88
  88    8888  888888    88    888888  8888    88
  88        88    88          88    88        88
  88          88  88          88  88          88
    88      88    8888      8888    88      88
      8888  88    88          88    88  8888
        888888    88888888888888    888888
          8888    88888888888888    8888
        8888888888888888888888888888888888
        8888888888888888  8888888888888888
          888888888888      88888888888
      888888        88      88        888888
      88          8888      8888          88
        8888888888              8888888888
```

Python takes the newlines you put in to type the figure as the newline escape character \n.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: My pleasure! Nice figure, by the way :)